# When to use JavaScript framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

If you're not creating a single page website or generating components on a page that get live updates is there any reason to use a JavaScript framework like angular, react etc?

Comment: depend on your needs, not the lack of them

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

But there are things like modules, cross-browser DOM manipulation utilities, routing, 2 way data binding etc. which don't come out-of-the-box with JavaScript but are provided by these frameworks which really helps quicken the development process.

Answer (score -4):

You probably shouldn’t use a JavaScript Framework. Instead, you should write modular, vanilla JavaScript. You also probably shouldn’t be considering a JavaScript MVC framework, especially if it’s going to be architected in the same way as a server rendered application (going to use site/application interchangeably). With a high performing site, you’ll likely squeak just as much perf out of a server rendered app as you would a “single page” app. Between sending less down the line to your users (reducing bandwidth and time to load), keeping their cache size small (making it more likely they’ll have something in cache next time), and reducing the memory footprint of your JavaScript (increasing perceived and on-page performance), you’re likely better off rendering on server.
If you absolutely must use a JavaScript framework (development skills across the team aren’t high enough to write vanilla JavaScript and there’s not time/money/interest in training the team and improving their skills, there is a real, not perceived, business need to support very old and outdated browsers, etc…) for server rendered applications, you should probably use jQuery. Yes, there’s Zepto and any number of other things you can use in place, but you should probably use jQuery.

Comment: You're not wrong but this comment is bordering on completely incoherent and it's very hard to figure out what you're actually saying.